# Why is _tcstod using my windows region settings when parsing a string?

Tags: c++, windows, parsing, regional-settings

Windows-related C++ question!

I'm trying to use _tcstod( ) to parse a string to obtain a float value. Normally, if I call

```
wchar_t* endPtr;
float result = static_cast<float>(_tcstod( "12.345678", &endPtr));
```

I get a float value of 12.345678 and endPtr behaves as expected. This actually misbehaves if I change my regional decimal delimiter in the Windows Region and Language settings. Specifically, if I change the decimal delimiter from "." to ",", suddenly _tcstod only returns a value of 12 rather than the whole thing. Anything after the . is chopped off.

Is there some way for me to parse the float value from the string while being agnostic to my Region settings?

Answer (score 1):

**Why is _tcstod using my windows region settings when parsing a string?**

Because it is supposed to.

**Is there some way for me to parse the float value from the string while being agnostic to my Region settings?**

Of course. The simplest way, in C++, is to use a stringstream and imbue it with a default or "C" locale.